# How to play minecraft with friends without using LAN (Hamachi is too slow)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

So I have some friends who want to play minecraft with me. The thing is we don't want to play on servers, as others may interrupt. So  is there a way for me to play minecraft with my friends without Hamachi? If i have to create a server, then how? Note: I don't have a strong pc. Ths!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to your router or Firewall you can forward the Port: 25565 so they can connect to your router and get dirrected to your Server if they connect with the Port.
If you dont have a router you have to manage this on your Intern Computer Firewall.

If you dont have access to your router there is no other way than using Hamachi or a Public Server.